# Multithreads performance

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, performance

I'm writing an application that listens on UDP for incoming messages. My main thread receives message after message from the network and passes each of them to a new thread for handling using an executor.

Each handling thread does the required processing on the message it's responsible on and adds it to a `LinkedBlockingQueue` that is shared between all the handling threads.

Then, I have a DB worker thread that drains the queue by block of 10000 messages and inserts the block of messages in the DB.

Since the arrival rate of messages may be high (more than 20000 messages per second), I thought that using `LOAD DATA INFILE` is more efficient. So, this DB worker threads drains the queue as said previously, creates a temporary file containing all the messages using a CSV format, and passes the created file to another thread using another executor. This new thread execute the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement using `JDBC`.

After testing my application, I think the performances are not so good, I'm looking for ways to improve performance both at the multithreading level and at the DB access level.

I precise that I use MySQL as DBMS.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to determine why your performance is poor.

E.g. its quite likely you don't need multiple threads if you are writing the data sequentially to a database which is far more likely to be your bottleneck. The problem with using multiple threads when you don't need to is that it add complexity which is an overhead in itself and it can be slower than using a single thread.

I would try and see what the performance is like if you do everything but load the data into the database. i.e. write the file and discard it.

Comment: I can use only the DB worker thread without the sub threads. In this case, the files will be written one after the other into the DB by this DB worker thread. But I thought that during the file is written (synchronous JDBC call), I could use this time to issue another file to the DB. Do you think this is unnecessary?

Comment: Its impossible to know without measuring how much difference each stage makes.  Even with twelve years experience optimising Java program, I am surprised what you find by measuring the performance of your system rather than guessing.

Comment: Do you have some resources to give me on how to measure performance of multithreaded applications?

Comment: I would time how long it takes with System.nanoTime() or remove piece of the process to see which bits are "keeping up" or not. You can use commercial CPU and Memory profilers and these will help improve performance but unless you do the basic research you won't know if you are optimising something which will make a difference anyway.

Comment: I've done some testing. By removing the part that writes the messages to the DB, I don't have the performance issue. When I enable the DB writes, the LinkedBlockingQueue's size grows continuously since the arrival rate is bigger than the DB writes rate. I'm trying to increase performance of DB writes but I don't know how.

Comment: How you do that is in how you tune your DB. There is only so much you can do in Java to work around DB performance issues, adding multiple threads is unlikely to help.

Comment: Could you give me a direction of what I can do in Java to work around this issue?

Comment: You need to determine what is the most efficient way to load data into your DB. Measure how long it takes to load via large transactions or external loaders and find the most efficient sizes for each.  Only then can you program Java to use that method and those sizes.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without any profiler output, but my (un-)educated guess is that the bottleneck is that you are writing your changes to a file on the hard drive, and then prompt your database to read and parse this file. Storage access is always much, much slower than memory access. So this is very likely much slower than just feeding the database the queries from memory.

But that's just guessing. Maybe the bottleneck is somewhere else where you or me would have never expected it. When you really want to know which part of your applications eats how much CPU time, you should use a profiler like Profiler4j to analyze your program.

Comment: Concerning the access to hard drive, I don't think I have the choice. A the end, I want my messages to be in the DB and since using LOAD DATA INFILE is more efficient, I have to write the messages in a file, unless there is another possibility?